# Replicate python Anaconda library on Internet less server

Tags: python, server, anaconda, devops

Currently I am using anaconda 3 with python version 3.6.4 and want to replicate the same environment(with all dependent libraries) in a remote desktop. 
The remote server doesn't have internet connection, is there any way to take a back up of my local anaconda and set it up in the remote Desktop. I can send back up of files(In case backed up) to the remote server.

Note :: Both my desktop and remote desktop is running on windows 10

Comment: Ever heard of docker ?

Comment: Not much aware of docker, can you tell a bit in details how it can help?

Comment: You can zip up the environment and then unzip it at the exact source location on the destination machine, then it should work, but make sure you activate the environment properly before using it

Comment: conda-pack is another tool to do so, but not sure whether it supports windows yet.